# Eloquent ORM is double-quoting tables and fields

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

First, I'm using Eloquent ORM from here: https://github.com/illuminate/database

Without Laravel, I just want to use the Eloquent Query Builder in my project.

But:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Connection;
use PDO;

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'root');
$connection = new Connection($pdo);

$user = $connection->table('user')->where('name', '=', 'foo')->get();
```

Is producing the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"user" where "name" = 'foo'' at line 1
```

Viewing the query that is performing in `\Illuminate\Database\Connection::select()`:

the `$query` variable equals to: `select * from "user" where "name" = ?`

It's an invalid query, because the doble quotes `"` around `user`:

```
mysql> select * from "user";
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"user"' at line 1
```

There is where Eloquent quotes with double quotes:
https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Grammar.php#L98

Comment: Have you looked at [Torch (previously IlluminateNonLaravel)?](https://github.com/mattstauffer/Torch/blob/master/components/database/index.php). It explains how to use Illuminate components outside of Laravel including Database.

Answer (score 4):

1. You can turn on the ansi_quotes sql mode within mysql (`SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';`), then schema object names within `"` are interpreted correctly, see mysql documentation on [schema object names for details](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html).
2. There may be a setting at eloquent level that tells eloquent query builder how to quote schema object names. Update: set the connection object's grammar to mysql, which will use backtick to quote object names.

   ```
   // set new grammar class

   DB::connection()->setQueryGrammar(new MySqlGrammar());
   ```

Comment: I edited my post, there is where eloquent is adding quotes: https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Grammar.php#L98 it's seems not configurable

Comment: @fj123x Yeah, I have just found that myself as well. Then either configure mysql to accept ansi quotes or you need to modify the grammar php code to use backticks instead of quotation marks.

Comment: Yes, now I'm doing it, but it seems a "workaround", it surprises me that a serious project like Laravel has that issue.. how is it working to the rest of the world?

Comment: I have never encountered this, but I also use Query Builder in Laravel not outside. Also that isn't eloquent.

Comment: There is a mysqlquerygrammar class as well: https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Query/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.php This uses backtick for wrapping schema object names. The connection object has a setQueryGrammar() method, use that to load the mysqlquerygrammar.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it adding:

`$connection->setQueryGrammar(new MySqlGrammar());`